# DialogFlow GCF fulfillment - The billing account for the owning project is disabled in state absent

Tags: dialogflow-es, google-cloud-billing

While my Dialogflow Firebase Google Cloud Function could be deployed without any issue a few weeks ago, I get now following error :

cloudfunctions.googleapis.com google.cloud.functions.v1.CloudFunctionsService.UpdateFunction projects/ac-outboundpv-ubuwat/locations/us-central1/functions/dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment yvan.decneef@gmail.com Failed to initialize region (action ID: b20b29316e3169d5): Error when configuring GCS bucket gcf-sources-900231667812-us-central1 in project ac-outboundpv-ubuwat. Cause: The billing account for the owning project is disabled in state absent

But this project has never been billed, so I don't have a clue what's happening here ...

Comment: In google cloud whenever a project includes a service that is not free of change, billing account should be enabled for that service. It does not matter if you cross threshold or not, in order to have access you have to enable billing.

Comment: Have you tried to disable and re-enable the billing account for your project?

Have you created a new project and associated your existing billing account on this newly created project?

Is the GCS bucket "gcf-sources-900231667812-us-central1" existing?

Comment: For future readers. The billing account is disabled. This is usually caused by a problem with the associated payment account. Remember to manage both Billing and Payment accounts.